# Find three numbers from a list that add up to a specific number

Tags: python, loops

How can I adjust the below code to find three numbers instead of two numbers yielding the target amount? I've already came across the code below from another question titled "Find two numbers from a list that add up to a specific number". Thank you.

```
numbers = [2, 4, 6, 8, 10] #revised so that 3 numbers add up to 12
target_number = 12


for i, number in enumerate(invoices[:-1]):  
    complementary = target_number - number
    if complementary in invoices[i+1:]:  number, complementary))
        break
else: 
    print("No solutions exist")
```

Comment: What happened when you tried to adjust the code yourself? How would you solve the problem with pencil and paper?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the numbers list is relatively small, you can use the [itertools](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.combinations) `combinations` function from the Python standard library.

```py
import itertools

numbers = [2, 4, 6, 8, 10]
target_number = 12

print([i for i in itertools.combinations(numbers, 3) if sum(i) == target_number])
```

Which gives the result:

```
[(2, 4, 6)]
```